# Encode Data in SQL Server DataBase

Tags: asp.net, security

I am working in ASP website , I dont the admin of the database server to know anything about the data stored in the database 
is there a way to encode the data in the database and decode it before put it in the Website form.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "encryption" because "encode" methods are usually well-known and easy to decode.

Yes you can encrypt your data before storing them to the database server and decrypt them after you pull them (the encrypted) from the database server.

However, there are somethings you should plan carefully.

1) where do you store your password for the encryption? if you use a script language , the passwords are also obvious to the admin. Even you use compiled binary code, it's not hard to see the passwords if you don't protect them carefully.

2) query performance can be effected severely.  If you encrypt the a column, you will not be able to search them using something "col=some_value".

It's very hard to protect your data from someone who controls your servers. You need take some cautions but you still need trust your admin.